# How exactly does this Sed command work?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, terminal

```
sed 's@.*/.*\.@.@'
```

The command is part of a larger command to find all file extensions in a directory.

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's@.*/.*\.@.@' | sort | uniq
```

I understand that `find` returns all files with an extension, I understand that sed returns just the extensions and then sort/uniq are self-explanatory.

At first, I was confused about the `@` symbol, but my best guess now guess is that it is part of Regex.

What really confuses me is a can't figure how it explicitly works, and the closest matching syntax I can find in a manual is `s/regexp/new/` which still doesn't match the syntax of the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `s/regexp/replacement/` syntax, the `/` can be replaced by any other character, such as `,`, `:`, `@`, etc. This is very useful if your regexp itself contains `/` characters, such as your example of `.*/.*\.`.

Your command could be simplified a bit, though:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' | sed 's/.*\././' | sort -u
```

Here, I simplified the regexp so that it no longer contains a `/` character.

Comment: Superb, I pretty much get the logic now. The sed command essentially says "find the text preceding the extension according to the regex, replace it with a dot". Thanks much. I understand your regex, plain and simple, unless I am missing something, in theirs they tried to explicitly account for parent directories which is redundant (I think...).